# Why does this Thread behave so strange?

Tags: java, multithreading

Let's think of following code fragment, that behaves as expected. Thread runs, then it's paused and then it's unpaused and finishes it's execution:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Executor exec = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        MyThread thread = new MyThread();
        exec.execute(thread);
        thread.pause();
        thread.pause(); // unpause
    }
```

Now let's add add some sleeping to thread so it's paused for a while:

```
public static void main(final String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Executor exec = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
        MyThread thread = new MyThread();
        exec.execute(thread);
        thread.pause();
        Thread.sleep(500); 
        thread.pause(); // unpause
    }
```

**But that code never finishes. Why ?**

Here's implementation of pause method, it checks private boolean field for pausing:

```
public synchronized void pause() {
        paused = (paused) ? false : true;
    }
```

And here is implementation of overriden run method:

```
@Override
    public void run() {
        // don't worry, I just need som dummy data to take some cpu time ;)
        PriorityQueue<Double> queue = new PriorityQueue<Double>();
        Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
        System.out.println("I stared");
        checkPause();
        // let's do some big computation
        for (int i=0; i<10000000; i++) { // 10 mio
            System.out.println(i);
            queue.add(random.nextDouble());
            if (i % 3 == 0) {
                queue.poll(); // more complex operation
            }
        }
        System.out.println("I'm done");
    }

private void checkPause() {
        synchronized (this) {
            if (paused) {
                while (paused != false) {
                    try {
                        wait();
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

When I tried debugging, I'll end on `wait()` method. Then it just waits :/

Comment: Are you sure the thread is actually pausing in 1st example?

Comment: Sorry for dumb question, but how do you know it actually paused? the pause is so short that event if it worked, I'm not sure you are able to see it (unless it's some extra debug prints that are not here...)

Comment: Ye I just System.out.println'd stuff like "pause - true" or "pause - false" and I saw that program did not finish yet ... anyway see my comment to Brian's answer, I got it now :) Thanx for help!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `wait()`, your thread waits until another thread calls its `notify()` method.

You're not calling `notify()` on the thread from your main thread.

Also note that `synchronize(this)` is the same thing as synchronizing the method; it's using the object itself as the lock. Once your thread hits `wait()` your main thread will block on `thread.unpause()` because the `checkPause()` method has the lock.

Comment: That was my thought, but it confuses me that this even works the first time...or maybe @Xorty simply thinks it works the first time...

Comment: from which place @main method should I call notify?

Comment: It didn't. The thread never hit wait(). `paused` would have only been flipped to true for a couple nanoseconds. If it's not declared `volatile` there's not even a guarantee that the thread could have even ever seen it (classic a-b-a problem with the local variable caching)

Comment: from pause method, oh :) -> adding notify() to pause() method solved that :) Thanks for explaining things.

Comment: @Xorty - your second call to the `unpause()` method cannot work because of the `synchronized(this)`. You would need to call `thread.notify()` before it.

Comment: no no i just added notify() to pause() method that is method of MyThread, so it always notifies itself I believe ...

Answer (score 1):

I see the `wait()`, but I don't see the corresponding [`notify()`](http://www.javamex.com/tutorials/synchronization_wait_notify.shtml) call that would wake the thread again.

Answer (score 1):

I think that in the 1st case, the thread doesn't pause at all, because if there is no `Thread.sleep(500);`, probably both `pause()` are called before `checkPause()` and the Thread never waits. In the 2nd case, the thread reaches `checkPause()` when pause = true and the it waits. since no one call `notify()`, it will not continue.